# Prevent Google Cloud Run Webhook Slowdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, azure-logic-apps, google-cloud-run

I have an Azure Logic App, that makes an HTTP request to a Python Flask API that is served via Google Cloud Run. The processing takes some time (I am converting a MP4 file using ffmpeg), so I had to implement the Flask API with a webhook mechanism, as the Logic App would timeout otherwise.

My problem is the bad performance of my container instance after the first response. As I understand it, this is due to Google limiting processing power after the request is "handled".

How can I circumvent this limitation? Is there a way to tell Cloud Run that the initial `POST 200` should not trigger the limiting of CPU access?

I am also open to using other services or implementations to allow for better performance when converting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Run is designed as an HTTP Request/Response system. You are billed for the time between the request and the response. Once your container returns a response, it can be idled or shutdown.

Your solution is to not return an HTTP response until the task is complete.

A new feature that is in beta is "minimum instances". This means that you can set the number of instances that should be running at all times. I have not verified if this feature affects or allows background tasks. However, there is no guarantee that your next request will go to the same container.

My recommendation is to combine Cloud Tasks with Cloud Run. You can start a task which can then make an HTTP request to Cloud Run and Cloud Tasks will wait until Cloud Run completes the processing. This will solve the idle/shutdown problem you are experiencing with Cloud Run.

**Links for more information:**

[Using minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances)

[Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)

[Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks)